# SED command not generating output file when called from app

Tags: java, bash, process, sed, runtime.exec

I am trying to write a java program that takes Strings in Java and replaces corresponding sequences of text in a perl script. Here is my code:

```
    String sedFirstLine = "'s/AAA/"+newFirstLine+"/'";
    String sedNewCntr = "'s/BBB/"+newCntr+"/'";
    String sedNewSpacing = "'s/SPACE/"+newSpacing+"/'";
    String sedNewDmax = "'s/MAX/"+newDmax+"/'";
    String sedInputFile = "/filepath/myPerlScript.pl" 
    String sedOutputFile = "/filepath/myNewPerlScript.pl";
    String[] cmdArray3 = {"sed", "-e", sedFirstLine,"-e", sedNewCntr,"-e", sedNewSpacing,"-e", sedNewDmax, "-e", sedInputFile, ">", sedOutputFile};
    Process runCmd;
    runCmd = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray3);
```

When I run this program, the output file "myNewPerlScript.pl" is not generated. I'm not sure what is wrong with what I've written. The Java variables that I was referring to earlier are "newFirstLine", "newCntr", etc.

Comment: Your code never actually *refers* to `sedOutputFile` or `sedInputFile`. How would you expect them to be used?

Comment: Any particular reason you invoke sed instead of doing the replacement with The regular expressions already present In Java?

Comment: I copied an old version of my code. Sorry about that, but I just edited it where I actually do call sedOutputFile and sedInputFile.

Comment: I thought I had to use "sed" to replace text in a file using UNIX. It seems really convenient, but I'm just having trouble making it work with my Java code.

Comment: `sedInputFile` and `sedOutputFile` never appear in your command line argument array.  Does your IDE warn you about unused variables?  Use `File` objects to represent files.   Also, remember that if you `exec` an external command, it's your responsibility to read the output, if any. Otherwise the process may block.  Finally, use the more modern `ProcessBuilder` class.

Comment: sedInputFile and sedOutputFile are in the String[] above. They may not have been there before because I accidentally copied an old version of my code before my edit. I'll try changing the input and output file parameters to files and see if that works.

Comment: Actually, wouldn't changing the data type to a File not work anyway since the String[] won't accept them?

Comment: You can call `getAbsolutePath()` on the `File` object before putting them into the `String[]`.  Or, using `ProcessBuilder`, when you fill in the `List<String>` for its `command` method.

Comment: As general tips:  Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the output redirection (i.e. the `>` ) is a functionality of the shell. In order to redirect the output of the command, you can invoke the command through a shell. For example, with this command

```
String[] cmdArray3 = {"bash", "-c", "sed 's/AAA/BBB/' inputfile > output"};
Process runCmd = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray3);
```

the output file should be created as expected.

Comment: Do I still need to separate each of the parameters? Or are there only three parameters: the shell, "-c", and my sed command?

Comment: @JeremyFisher You pass the entire command as a single `String`. Only three parameters should be passed to `exec`

Answer (score 4):

The `ProcessBuilder` version:

```
String sedFirstLine = "'s/AAA/"+newFirstLine+"/'";
String sedNewCntr = "'s/BBB/"+newCntr+"/'";
String sedNewSpacing = "'s/SPACE/"+newSpacing+"/'";
String sedNewDmax = "'s/MAX/"+newDmax+"/'";

File directory = new File("/filepath");
File sedInputFile = new File(directory, "myPerlScript.pl"); 
File sedOutputFile = new File(directory, "myNewPerlScript.pl");
List<String> commandLine = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(commandLine,
    "sed",
    "-e", sedFirstLine,
    "-e", sedNewCntr,
    "-e", sedNewSpacing,
    "-e", sedNewDmax);
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commandLine);
pb.directory(directory);
pb.redirectInput(Redirect.from(sedInputFile));
pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.to(sedOutputFile));
Process sed = pb.start();
// Watch sed.getErrorStream() for errors.
```

See the `ProcessBuilder` [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

You need not worry about shells, beacuse Java takes care of the redirection, as @Chris Stratton pointed out.  Just make sure you handle the error stream somehow; if there are problems and too much error output piles up, the process may block.  But the original method has the same problem.

Comment: "Let the JRE worry about shells." - no, no shell is involved.  In this case, Java is doing the redirection, not a shell.

Comment: You're right.  I should have written that the programmer need not worry about shells.  Another advantage of this is that the system may not have `bash` available, but may have `sed`,  That's a trifle odd, but it could happen.  I'll edit my post.

Comment: Yes, not depending on the shell (or the ability/syntax by which it might accept a command on its own command line) makes this answer very much worth considering for portability.

Comment: If you really wanted portability, you wouldn't resort to an external program.  On the other hand, `sed` is probably faster than the Java equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the following line:

```
String[] cmdArray3 = {"sed", "-e", sedFirstLine,"-e", sedNewCntr,"-e", sedNewSpacing,"-e", sedNewDmax, "-e", sedFile};
```

to:

```
String[] cmdArray3 = {"sed", "-e", sedFirstLine,"-e", sedNewCntr,"-e", sedNewSpacing,"-e", sedNewDmax, sedFile};
```

Notice the extra -e parameter that you have.

Comment: The extra -e parameter was actually part of my old code which I changed to ">". Sorry. But I tried it without the ">" and the file is still not being generated :/

Comment: Try it with ">" and it will work: String[] cmdArray3 = {"sed", "-e", sedFirstLine,"-e", sedNewCntr,"-e", sedNewSpacing,"-e", sedNewDmax, ">", sedOutputFile };

Comment: @user1521213 If you construct the command array like this, the output redirection character (i.e. the `>`) will not be parsed, but it will be passed as an argument to the command. You can either invoke the command through a shell (like in my answer), or use a `ProcessBuilder`, like in Eric's answer.

Comment: No, this will not work.  ">" is a command to a shell, and no shell is being used here.