# How do i run a Linux terminal cmd from a java program

Tags: java, cmd, rrd

I am trying to call my rrdtool cmd from a java class, not sure how to go about it.

I have tested my RRDTool cmd from my terminal and it is successful, see below.

```
rrdtool update mydb.rrd 1385056701:6:5
```

How do i execute this cmd from a java class?

Comment: See : [how-to-run-linux-commands-in-java-code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403226/how-to-run-linux-commands-in-java-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below command format to run your Linux command.

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = r.exec(yourcmd);
```

Please go through [Running unix command from Java](http://www.coderanch.com/t/390831/java/java/Running-UNIX-command-Java) and [Unable to run Unix command in Java-Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429424/unable-to-run-unix-command-from-java-program)

Hope you get your answers here.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
        public class ShellTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException, java.lang.InterruptedException {
        // Get runtime
        java.lang.Runtime rt = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime();
        // Start a new process: UNIX command ls
        java.lang.Process p = rt.exec("ls");
        // Show exit code of process
        System.out.println("Process exited with code = " + rt.exitValue());
    }
}
```

[also check here for more details](http://blog.art-of-coding.eu/executing-operating-system-commands-from-java/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Runtime#exec for this purpose. If you want a Java-like control over the started process, there is a great library called zt-exec that makes handeling processes much easier. The ProcessBuilder is also offering a minor API improvement over Runtime#exec that ships with the Java standard library.

Something you have to take care of is that Java processes come with very little buffer for the in- and output streams what blocks processes once these buffers run full. This happens silently. zt-exec can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403226/how-to-run-linux-commands-in-java-code)(As answered by paxdiablo):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s;
        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -aF");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println("line: " + s);
            p.waitFor();
            System.out.println ("exit: " + p.exitValue());
            p.destroy();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
```

Also check **[java.lang.Runtime.exec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29)** for details.

> Executes the specified string command in a separate process.
>
> This is a convenience method. An invocation of the form exec(command)
>   behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation exec(command, null,
>   null).

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at :
https://github.com/OpenNMS/opennms/blob/master/opennms-rrd/opennms-rrd-rrdtool/opennms-rrdtool-api/src/main/java/org/opennms/netmgt/rrd/rrdtool/JniRrdStrategy.java

for a real life use of rrdtool in java.
Or at
https://code.google.com/p/rrd4j/

For a native version of rrdtool in java.

Answer (score 0):

I runned my rrdtool command in java program as follow:

```
    Process p = null;
    try {

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/rrdtool","lastupdate", rrdPath);

        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        p = pb.start();
        int exitVal = p.waitFor();
        if (exitVal == 0)
            System.out.println("exitVal of rrdLastUpdate is Successful");
        else
            System.out.println("exitVal of rrdLastUpdate is Abnormal");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Problem in executing rrdlastupdate()");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }//end of try-catch
```

I hope this be useful for U :) I worked with some other rrdtool commands in java. if you need more help, I will be happy to help.